# cron - Running multiple cron jobs located in etc/cron.d

Tags: bash, docker, cron

In my docker container, I have multiple cron jobs that need to be ran, with each doing a different thing:

- Some cron jobs will import a module
- Some cron jobs will activate the imported module
- Finally, some cron jobs will do a cleanup

This is the order in which they should run.

Currently, cron is not a running process in my container however, including the following in my `entrypoint` script has it running in the foreground:

```
#!/bin/bash
cron -n -s -m off
```

With this included, it does run the cron jobs. However, a key point is that each set of cron jobs (import, activate, cleanup) uses one of three bash scripts to perform their tasks. So, for example, the cron jobs that activate a module will have the following format:

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * root /tmp/moduleActivation.sh  <module> <version>
```

Each activation cron job will use a bash script that takes in two parameters and the bash script will activate it as so. The way these scripts are set up, only one instance can be running at any one time.

With my current setup, it will attempt to run each cron job at the same time, which is not my desired result as multiple instances of the activation script will attempt to run at the same time, which can't happen.

I am quite new to cron - how can I prevent this from happening and have the cron jobs run in the desired order? Will a crontab file take precedence in some way if I was to include one?

Comment: Cron just runs some shell command when its scheduled time comes around.  It doesn't have any notion of "setup" or "cleanup" phases, and it doesn't have any protection against running multiple jobs if any run longer than a minute.  Are you potentially looking for a different sort of job runner?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure, these cron jobs are ran in another system (main difference is crond is used there, while I am using cron - when I try to start crond, my container doesn't start (CrashLoopBackoff)).

Looking at the cron logs in this other system,  they get activated through cron